# Spring Mongo converters not registred

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-mongo

I've registered a set of **Mongo** converters (including `Jsr310Converters`) but it does not convert `LocalDate` to `Date` (since canConvertFromLocalDateToDate is equal to `false`)

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

@Autowired
MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory),
            new MongoMappingContext());
    converter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("_");

    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
    converters.add(new GeoPointConverter());

    converters.addAll(Jsr310Converters.getConvertersToRegister());
    converters.addAll(JodaTimeConverters.getConvertersToRegister());
    converters.addAll(ThreeTenBackPortConverters.getConvertersToRegister());

    converter.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(CustomConversions.StoreConversions.NONE, converters));

   //is FALSE !
    boolean canConvertFromLocalDateToDate = converter.getConversionService().canConvert(LocalDate.class, Date.class); 

    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);

    return mongoTemplate;

}
```

When I try to store some entities with `LocalDate` fields I get an exception:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.LocalDate] to type [java.util.Date]

Answer (score 1):

In fact I found that I had 2 instances of MappingMongoConverter at runtime. So I just reused the instance created by spring instead of instantiating a new one:
    @Autowired
    MappingMongoConverter converter;

The full snippet is:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {


@Autowired 
MappingMongoConverter converter;

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
  // NO NEED TO INSTANTIATE NEW MappingMongoConverter 
  //MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory), new MongoMappingContext());

  converter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("_");

  List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
  converters.add(new GeoPointConverter());

  converters.addAll(Jsr310Converters.getConvertersToRegister());
  converters.addAll(JodaTimeConverters.getConvertersToRegister());
  converters.addAll(ThreeTenBackPortConverters.getConvertersToRegister());

  converter.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(CustomConversions.StoreConversions.NONE, converters));
  //is FALSE !
  boolean canConvertFromLocalDateToDate = converter.getConversionService().canConvert(LocalDate.class, Date.class); 
  converter.afterPropertiesSet();
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);

  return mongoTemplate;

}
```

Comment: You just made my day ! I was having the same issue, and it was driving me crazy ! Nevertheless, I had to call the method MappingMongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet() in order to register the converters and make it work. Thank you.

Comment: You're right @Pear, I've add it to my answer. Thanks !